# can't create @ViewChild due to *ngIf statement

Tags: angular, angular-material

this is my ViewChild element:

```
ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

it points to a form element inside

```
<div *ngIf="editFormDataLoaded"> <form>  ... </form></div>
```

the variable editFormDataLoaded is set to true when all data from http request are downloaded and transformed.

when template renders I get an error that variable 'trigger is undefined'

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't access properties of `trigger` while it is undefined. You can't get a reference to an element or component that isn't there. As long as `editFormDataLoaded` is `false` `trigger` will be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I know, but how to pass this? Create viewchild dynamically?

Comment: ViewChild is view query. It's supposed to update trigger dynamically. If it's not there, it's not there. If you have no ability to catch a moment when it appears, there is likely a design problem.